# Connection error when trying to use VNC to view behat tests

Tags: docker, moodle, vnc

I've just installed [moodle-docker](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker) in my computer and I'm trying to run some behat tests. The tests are running and passing. I'm trying now to actually see those test through VNC, following the **Using VNC to view behat tests** section. However, when I try to connect from VNC I get an error:

> connect: the requested direction is not valid in this context (10049)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting port to 127.0.0.1:PI instead of 0.0.0.0:PI as the guide suggests.